# Matched pair of Atmega168 running at slightly different clock speeds

Tags: arduino

I have four RFBEEs from Seeedstudio.

I've been able to reprogram them with identical code. But one of them seems to be running at a slightly different speed.

I first noticed it when establishing a serial connection to change the Baud rate.
regardless of me using 9600, 19200 or 38400 the end of each response from one  of  the devices was scrambled, so instead of "1 ok" I was getting "1 o€" or something.

Each device has a heartbeat LED and I've noticed that the malfunctioning one is running at a different speed, it appears to be losing aproximately 1  second in every ten.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem is?
I've disconnected everything from the RFBEES except the 3v3 GND Tx and RX pins. I'm communicating with them using an Arduino Mega.

Is it possible that the fuses might be set differently for one of the devices?

the results for calling Serial.println(F_CPU) in the loop() are:

For a functioning device

```
8000000
8000000
8000000
8000000
8000000
```

For the malfunctioning one

```
80000Cá800Cá8000j
80000
á800
á800Cá80j
800Cá80j
800j
800
á80000Cá800
á8000j
80000
á80j
8000Cá80000
á8000j
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check would be whether the malfunctioning Arduino is using its internal RC oscillator or the external crystal.  The internal RC is slower and considerably less accurate than a crystal, and could certainly lead to the kinds of timing errors you're seeing.

You can check which oscillator is being used by [reading the fuse bits](http://riktronic.prismaticmedia.com/?p=15) of the chip.

If the external crystal is being used, there may just be a hardware issue with the malfunctioning device.